# gtk# window freezes when it maximizes

Tags: c#, gtk#

I've created an application with Glade and GTK# in windows XP:

- at startup window is not maximized
- I click on "Search" and a listview is filled with data from a database:

  [image http://www.microline.eu/Capture-1.jpg](http://www.microline.eu/Capture-1.jpg)
- I click on maximize button the window freezes and does not respond

any suggestions?

Thanks

### Added informations

1. On linux it works well
2. No code on maxime routine
3. My idea is that there is a bug in resizing procedure in GTK# for Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to diagnose your problem without knowing what your code looks like - do you have any resize routines?

To solve your problem, I'd narrow down the potential culprits. Remove or hide one or more controls until you can find which control is responsible for the freeze on maximize.

Once you narrow down which control is causing the issue, determine whether it's the data in the control causing the issue. If it's the grid, see if the freeze still happens when there's no data in the grid.

Comment: I know, it's difficult to solve without seeing the code ...thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

If I change property *Window position* from *Always center* to *None*, then maximize works well.

Comment: Sounds like a potential bug in GTK or GTK#. I suggest reporting this to the Mono folks.